# Can't see some programs from Console2 or Powershell

Tags: command-line, shell, console

I use [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) to run various shells (git bash, powershell, cmd).  However, there are some programs that aren't accessible when I run Console2 or Powershell that are accessible from a plain cmd prompt.  Why might that be, and how can I fix it?

For example, the program `bcdedit` can't even be seen in `C:\Windows\System32\` when in the other shells (but shows up fine in cmd and Windows Explorer, and is on the PATH [i.e. runnable from any directory] in cmd).

I've also installed the [Elevation PowerToys](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.06.elevation.aspx) on my machine, but, again, the `elevate` command again only works from cmd.

Comment: what you mean with "cant be seen" ? or is that they don't get executed when invoked from the commandline?

Comment: Can't be seen means doing `ls bcdedit` from powershell doesn't show any files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't replicate this on my system (win7 64-bit, console2 beta version 2.00.147), but it sounds like some madness I fought once upon a time with a 32-bit app launching a 32-bit cmd.exe and getting lost in WOW64's system32 folder (%systemroot%\SysWOW64).

If you're running a 64-bit version of windows, I'd suggest you check your task manager to confirm whether console.exe and cmd.exe are 32-bit or 64-bit.

I was able to work around the issue at that time by creating a symlink to the 64-bit system folder and launching cmd.exe explicitly from there in my 32-bit process.

```
cd \windows
mklink /d sysnative system32
```

then make my 32-bit app launch \windows\sysnative\cmd.exe

Very clunky work around, but it may help you, if you're experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Ah, looks like it is a 32/64-bit issue.  I'm able to get it to work from a 64-bit Powershell command line.  I'm using the 32-bit Console2 because the 64-bit version wasn't able to host git bash...

Comment: Awesome, creating the sysnative symlink and adding it to my path it (so far) making everything work seemlessly.  Thanks!